# Where can I learn about solving Big-Oh problems that are written in algebra?

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Where can I learn about solving Big-Oh problems that are written in algebra?

Such as this

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (3i + 2n) = O(n^2)$$

Comment: Can someone explain the process to solving/proving this perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Texts on discrete math usually cover this. Sedgewick and Flajolet's ["Introduction to the analysis of algorithms"](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home/) covers the manipulations to combine such notations (for deriving approximations) in chapter 4. Best presentation I've seen.