# $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (3i + 2n)$

Tags: summation

I want to verify what would be the simplified solved version of this summation.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (3i + 2n)$$

Would it be this?

$$ \frac32n^2 + \frac32n + 2n^2  $$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340465/where-can-i-learn-about-solving-big-oh-problems-that-are-written-in-algebra

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340984/question-concerning-big-o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (3i + 2n)=3\sum_{i=1}^{n} i+2n\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1=3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+2n\cdot n$$